# Calculate $P(X_n = 1)$ for $X_n = \lfloor(2^nw)\rfloor \ (mod 2)$

Tags: probability

On the probability space $([0,1], B([0,1]), \lambda)$
define $X_n (w) = \lfloor(2^nw)\rfloor \ (mod 2)$ for $w \in [0,1]$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Im trying to calculate $P(X_n = 1)$. What am I doing wrong?

$$
P(X_n =1 ) = P(\lfloor(2^nw)\rfloor \ (mod 2) = 1 ) = 
P(2k-1 \leq 2^nw < 2k )= \frac1{2^n}
$$

Comment: Is $w$ uniformly random on $[0,1]$?

Comment: $W$is the argument of $X_n$ that is, $X_n(w) = \lfloor 2^n w \rfloor (mod 2) $ @alexR.

Comment: Then how is $X$ a random variable?

Comment: I have updated the question. Its a part of the question to provet that X_n are random variables. @alexr

Comment: Please explain the notation better. Is $\lambda$ lebesgue measure? If yes then $w$ is likely uniformly random on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Yes its the lebesgue. @alexr

Comment: But if $w$ is uniformly random then arent my calculations correct? @alexr

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\lfloor(2^nw)\rfloor\equiv 1 \mod 2$ iff $\lfloor(2^nw)\rfloor$ is odd and takes values in the set $\{1,3,\ldots,2^n-1\}$. It means that $2^nw$ lies in one of the following segments:
$$1\leq 2^nw < 2 \ \text{ or } \ 3\leq 2^nw < 4 \ \text{ or } \ \ldots \text{ or } \ 2\cdot 2^{n-1}-1\leq 2^nw < 2\cdot 2^{n-1}.$$
The segments are disjoint, therefore
$$
P(X_n =1 ) = P(\lfloor(2^nw)\rfloor(\mathrm{mod} 2) = 1) = 
\sum_{k=1}^{2^{n-1}}P(2k-1 \leq 2^nw < 2k )= \ldots
$$